# Пример аутентификации и авторизации для api на nodejs с express, passport, mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport

Ищу документированный и рабочий пример как организовать аутентификацию и авторизацию для api на nodejs с express, passport, mongodb без использования callback, а на базе async/await.

Ниже приведены

- код функции login, который формирует token в случае успеха
- код для создания user.

Мне нужно реализовать проверку на разрешение на создание пользователя только для тех кто прошел аутентификацию.

Понимаю, что нужно написать функцию (helper) которая из header будет считывать token и проверять его на валидность и в случае успеха разрешать запускать функцию create. Не могу понять как это сделать на базе passport и посредством async/await.

Routes

```
router.post('/',  controller.create); //создание user.
router.post('/login',  controller.login)
```

Функции:

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    const db = req.app.db;

    const { email, password } = req.body
    if (!email || !password) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(400, 'Missing required email and password fields');
    }

    const user = await db.users.findOne({ email: email, isDeleted: false });

    if (!user) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(404, `User with email: ${email} does not exists`);
    }

    const resultComparePassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!resultComparePassword) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(401, 'Password incorrect');
    };

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { 
        id: user._id, 
        email: user.email, 
        role: user.role
      }, 
      process.env.JWT_KEY, 
      { 
        expiresIn: "1h" 
      });

    return res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      statusCode: 200,
      message: "Login successful",
      token: token 
  });

  } catch (err) {

    next(err);

  }
};

const create = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    const db = req.app.db;

    const {userName, userEmail, userRole, userImage, userPassword} = req.body;

    const params = {
      name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
      role: userRole,
      registrationDate: new Date(),
      lastLoginDate: null,
      image: userImage,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(userPassword, 10),
      isDeleted: false
    };

    result = await db.users.updateOne(
      { email: userEmail, isDeleted: false },
      { $setOnInsert: params },
      { upsert: true });

      if (result.matchedCount > 0) {
        throw new ErrorHandler(404, `User with email: ${userEmail} already exists`);
      }

      if (result.upsertedCount == 1) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          status: "success", 
          message: `Created a new user: ${userEmail}` 
        });
      };      

      throw new ErrorHandler(400, 'Bad request');

  } catch (err) {

    next(err);

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел хороший документированный пример с исходным кодом на github.com

https://www.codementor.io/mohdraheem06/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-jwt-using-async-await-lji074q5p